# Undefined references when compiling project with libvpx

Tags: c++, mingw, libvpx

I've build libvpx.a and headers with MSYS (for MinGW). When I'm trying to compile an [example](http://www.webmproject.org/docs/webm-sdk/example_simple_decoder.html) a lot of undefined references to vpx members occurs:

```
g++ -m32 -static    -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/test1 build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o -L/D/Libraries/libvpx/ -lvpx
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:107: undefined reference to `die'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:109: undefined reference to `vpx_video_reader_open'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:111: undefined reference to `die'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:114: undefined reference to `die'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:116: undefined reference to `vpx_video_reader_get_info'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:118: undefined reference to `get_vpx_decoder_by_fourcc'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:120: undefined reference to `die'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:125: undefined reference to `die_codec'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:127: undefined reference to `vpx_video_reader_read_frame'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:132: undefined reference to `vpx_video_reader_get_frame'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:134: undefined reference to `die_codec'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:137: undefined reference to `vpx_img_write'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:144: undefined reference to `die_codec'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:149: undefined reference to `vpx_video_reader_close'
```

All includes made, lib is linked...
So what am I doing wrong?

PS: Maybe it's not enough to link the libvpx.a file, and I also need the .c files that come with the sources (if so, I do not understand what for the .a lib file is needed)?

Comment: We'll need to see you `main.cpp` as well

Comment: @MikeKinghan, the word "example" in my question has a link to code I tried to build statically. Maybe reading and writing webm is not included in libvpx.a? If it is so, how can I create and read webm files in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just copied and pasted blindly from the example.

The functions `die_codec` and `vpx_video_*` all come from `tools_common.c` (https://github.com/webmproject/libvpx/blob/master/tools_common.c) and `video_reader.h` (https://github.com/webmproject/libvpx/blob/master/video_reader.c), which I believe is not a core part of the libvpx sdk (see here: http://www.webmproject.org/docs/webm-sdk/files.html).

In order for your example to work, you will need to copy-paste those files (both the `.c` and `.h` files) as well and include them in your `main.cc` file.

Comment: I already understood this. I thought that library for working with WebM should include functions to read and write files of this format. Deceived myself... Thanks for response!